# I want to get data from a DevExtreme DataGrid in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get data from only one column in a DevExtreme DataGrid in JavaScript and save it.

Here is the datagrid and I want to get the "nSupplierCode" column.

```
<div class="content-block">
                @(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid()
                    .ID("ID_gridSuppliers")
                    .DataSource(Model.MainSuppliers)
                    .LoadPanel(loadPanel => loadPanel.Enabled(true))
                    .RowAlternationEnabled(true)
                    .Scrolling(scrolling => scrolling.Mode(GridScrollingMode.Standard))
                    .Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Single))
                    .ShowBorders(true)
                    .HeaderFilter(headerFilter => headerFilter.Visible(true))
                    .FilterRow(filterRow => filterRow.Visible(true).ApplyFilter(GridApplyFilterMode.Auto))
                    .OnSelectionChanged("attire.supplier.suppliers.OnSupplierSelected")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add()
                        .DataField("nSupplierCode")
                        .Caption("Code")
                        .Width("40%");

                        columns.Add()
                        .DataField("cSupplierName")
                        .Caption("Name")
                        .Width("60%");
                    })
                )
            </div>
```

Assume that the grid is already populated and you just need to write the function in a .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [];
    var tdlist = $('#ID_gridSuppliers').find('.dx-datagrid-rowsview .dx-data-row td:nth-child(2)');   //td:nth-child(2) get the second column
    tdlist.each(function (i, td) {
        data.push($(td).text());
    })
    console.log(data);
})
```